# python inherited dataclass sets mandaroy parameter in the parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I have 3 data classes in Python 3.1x, a base class with 2 mandatory attributes and 2 subclasses which should set one of the two attributes to a fixed default value. The base class itself is not used directly, only the subclasses.

In reality, there are many more parameters. I have seen that I could write the `__init__` function myself, but I was hoping that it would work without it.

```
from typing import Optional

import re
       
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class __Sensor():
    name: str
    type: str

    unique_id: Optional[str] = None
    

    def cleanName(self):
        return re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', self.name).lower()
        
    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.unique_id is None:
            self.unique_id = self.type + "_" + self.cleanName()

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class BinarySensor(__Sensor):
    some_attrib: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.type = "binary_sensor"

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class PowerSensor(__Sensor):
    some_attrib: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
        self.type = "power_sensor"

mySensor = __Sensor(name="mySensor", type="Dummy")
print(mySensor)

myBinSensor = BinarySensor(name="myBinarySensor", some_attrib="a lot of stuff here")
print(myBinSensor)
```

But i got error

```
    myBinSensor = BinarySensor(name="myBinarySensor", some_attrib="a lot of stuff here")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BinarySensor.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'type'
```

Comment: I would make `type` a *class* attribute that each subclass defines, rather than an instance attribute that `__post_init__` defines.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix three things:

1. Make `type` a class attribute that each subclass defines once, rather than an instance attribute that `__post_init__` has to define for each instance separately.
2. Make `unique_id` have type `str`, as each instance *will* have one. What's optional is the argument to `__init__` that can be used to initialize it: that can be define as a separate `InitVar`.
3. If the base class is at all "private", just use `_Sensor` as the name. Otherwise, use `Sensor`.

---

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar
from typing import Optional, ClassVar

import re


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Sensor:
    type: ClassVar[str] = "dummy"
    name: str

    # These must have different names; decide which one should
    # be unique_id and which should be, well, something different.
    unique_id: str = field(init=False)
    unique_id_: InitVar[Optional[str]] = None


    def cleanName(self):
        return re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', self.name).lower()

    def __post_init__(self, unique_id_):
        if unique_id_ is None:
            unique_id_ = self.type + "_" + self.cleanName()

        self.unique_id = unique_id_


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class BinarySensor(Sensor):
    type: ClassVar[str] = "binary_sensor"
    some_attrib: str


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class PowerSensor(Sensor):
    type: ClassVar[str] = "power_sensor"
    some_attrib: str


mySensor = Sensor(name="mySensor")
print(mySensor)

myBinSensor = BinarySensor(name="myBinarySensor", some_attrib="a lot of stuff here")
print(myBinSensor)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @chepner.

To 1: My problem is that this is not just `type` but rather 5-10 attributes. And I didn't want to repeat myself in every derivation. I thought that is the idea of inheritance: take all attributes; specify some of them if necessary.

But in principle that could work, yes. Thank you.

To 2: Ok, I'll have to have a look and think about it :-)

Regarding 3: Yes, it's also called _Sensor in my case, the underscore is just a simplification, but good advice, thanks.

Comment: But you (or the class) is repeating the *assignment* unnecessarily if you do it every time `__post_init__` is called. Make the assignment *once* per subclass, because this isn't (I presume) something that varies from instance to instance of the same subclass.